# Spring application throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am new to programming. when I run the program, program throwing an Array Index out of bounds exception. using spring and java to program. I am creating a text editor object in the main class. the error is in 
SpellChecker constructor's system out println line.
if I remove the 'a' variable from that line, code runs with no errors. 
Main class:

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Bean.xml");

    TextEditor te = (TextEditor)context.getBean("textEditor");
    te.spellCheck();
}
```

}

Text editor class:

```
public class TextEditor {
private SpellChecker spellChecker;

public TextEditor(SpellChecker spellChecker){
    System.out.println("Inside TestEditor constructor");
    this.spellChecker=spellChecker;
}
public void spellCheck(){
    spellChecker.checkSpelling();
}
```

}

Spell Checker class:

```
public class SpellChecker {
String a;

public SpellChecker(String a){
    this.a=a;
    System.out.println("Inside SpellChecker constructor " +a);
}

public void checkSpelling(){
    System.out.println("Inside checkSpelling");
}
```

}

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="textEditor" class="TextEditor">
    <constructor-arg ref="spellChecker"/>
</bean>

<bean id="spellChecker" class="SpellChecker">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="raviya"/>
</bean>
```

stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 24882 out of bounds for length 1064
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:112)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:86)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:888)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:600)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:888)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at MainApp.main(MainApp.java:6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

1. Add `setA()` method in `SpellChecker` class
2. Modify the XML to set the value of the field in this way

```html
  <bean id="spellChecker" class="SpellChecker">
       <property name="a" value="raviya"/>
   </bean>
```

You're injecting a value into a field through the setter injection. You can read more for example [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial-dependency-injection-by-setter-method) and in the [Spring documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/).

Comment: Why should he switch from constructor injection to setter injection? Especially if `a` is a mandatory one.

Comment: @Ziumin yes then?

Comment: If the answer is ok for you, please accept it and/or upvote it by clicking on the up arrow on the left side of the answer. Then ask another question and, if you want, add here a link to the new question.